# OAuth does not accept Non-top-level domain

Tags: google-drive

I have been using Google drive API since July and it accepted a non Top-Level local domain (not end with .com,.io,.org...)as whitelisted domain for OAuth.

But yesterday when I try to whitelist another domain, it shows that it doesn't allow non Top-Level Domain any longer.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFbh8.png)

Please assist on this because my entire company is using this non Top-Level domain internally. We can afford to change the domain as it involved a lot of changes. Please advise what should I do.

Comment: Your company made a very expensive mistake and now the bill is due.